# How to Search With Vendor Name As Well?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I have a table with invoice data in it and a invoice is related to the vendor so i also displayed the vendor name in the table, i'm using search feature it works when i search invoice number, but when i want to search with vendor name, its not working.

i did something like this:

**I DID THIS IN SCRIPT**

```js
mounted() {
    Fire.$on("searching", () => {
      let query = this.$parent.search;
      axios
        .get("api/findVTI?q=" + query)
        .then(data => {
          this.ticketInvoices = data.data;
        })
        .catch();
    });
```

**I MADE A ROUTE**

```js
Route::get('findVTI', 'API\TicketInvoiceController@searchVTI');
```

**IN MY INVOICE CONTROLLER I DID THIS**

```js
    public function searchVTI()
    {
        if($search = \Request::get('q')){
            $VTI = TicketInvoice::where(function($query) use ($search){
                $query->where('ticket_invoice_no','LIKE',"%$search%")
                      ->orWhere('ticket_invoice_grand_total','LIKE',"%$search%")
                      ->orWhere('vendor_company_name','LIKE',"%$search%");
            })->paginate(10);
        }else{
            return TicketInvoice::paginate(10);
        }
        return $VTI;
    }
```

When i write this line:
`->orWhere('vendor_company_name','LIKE',"%$search%");` i got an error in console that, `vendor_company_name` does not exist in `ticket_invoices`.

I play around with many thing but didn't succeed...

Image For Better Understanding:
[image]

Comment: obviously the column is NOT named `vendor_company_name` maybe it is named `related_vendor` instead?

Comment: @NikosM. I resolved my issue by the answer below Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isnt working because i write orWhere('vendor_company_name','LIKE',"%$search%"), but vendor is relationship and i need to write instead last orWhere something like:

```js
->orWhereHas('vendor', function($query) use ($search){
    $query->where('vendor_company_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get at a lower level, you need to look at vendor.vendor_company_name you are skipping the vendor part.

```
->orWhere('vendor.vendor_company_name','LIKE',"%$search%");
```

Comment: I resolved my issue by the answer below Thanks for your support. @Linuxuser07